# Django: Model does not appear on admin panel

Tags: python, django

This is the model that I want to show on the admin panel. I'm registering the model via `admin.py` file with `admin.site.register(Ad)`. I tried to re-write the register line twice, and an exception appeared that the model is already registered.

```
class Ad(AdModel):
    plate = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    ad_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=AdTypes.get_choices(),
        default=AdTypes.OFFERING,
    )
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        help_text='In cents'
    )
    location = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=AdLocations.get_choices(),
        default=AdLocations.VILNIUS,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    approved_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='approved_by', null=True
    )
```

The two base models:

```
class UUIDBaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AdModel(UUIDBaseModel):
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This is really strange, maybe that could be the problem because of the naming 'Ad'? I have a serializer for this model and everything works just fine, but the admin panel doesn't want to display it.

`views.py`

```
class AdCreateViewSet(ModelViewSet, CreateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = AdCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ('plate', 'description', 'user__email')
    queryset = Ad.objects.select_related('user')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = User.objects.first()
        serializer.save(user=user)  # self.request.user)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class AdCreateSerializer(CustomAdSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        exclude = ['expires_at']
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using a superuser/admin? Could be that you don't have permissions

Comment: Did you add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` settings?

Comment: Did you run syncdb after you added this class in models.py?

Comment: Can you share your `admin.py`? and what is your admin page in home page ? in this photo you are in user section ...

Comment: Hey everyone, I've configured everything, but I think that could be all of permissions, how should and where should I add them? @bdbd

Comment: Try to see first if you see it with a superuser

Comment: I'm trying this with a superuser already @bdbd